# Failed resolution of: Lorg/spongycastle/crypto/engines/AESFastEngine - Android

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I'm trying to add password on PDF using itext but it crashes

My Code

```
public void encryptPdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.setEncryption(USER, OWNER,
            PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Error

```
Didn't find class "org.spongycastle.crypto.engines.AESFastEngine" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.osdifa.pdfreader-OTsVqJob5vpuiGdFVuZWig==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.osdifa.pdfreader-OTsVqJob5vpuiGdFVuZWig==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.osdifa.pdfreader-OTsVqJob5vpuiGdFVuZWig==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
```

It is Crashing At

```
stamper.close();
```

Comment: Have you added SpongyCastle to your libraries?

Comment: @mkl I have not added SpongyCastel

Comment: Then that explains why classes from it cannot be found. Please add the required dependencies.